# Implementing "this page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave"

Tags: javascript

This is a warning that Firefox raises when I want to leave certain pages. Based on the pages I've seen this on and that this warning appears when I try to close the page after filling in the forms, I can only assume that it's working on a dynamic page. Which technology is used to implement this functionality? How can I implement it myself on a simple hello-world page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You basically implement a handler for `beforeunload` event. This allows you to warn your users that they have unsaved data.

Pseudo Code:

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function warnUsers()
  {
    if (needToConfirm)
    {
      // check to see if any changes to the data entry fields have been made
      if(changesPresent) {
            return message to display
      }
      else {
      // no changes - return nothing      
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's a very good article that discusses this in depth: <s>http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/100604-1.shtml</s> **Note:** This link no longer exists. Here is a copy of it from the Wayback Machine:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134123/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/100604-1.shtml

**Note:** There is `onunload` event also but that fires *after* the page has unloaded, hence is too late to take any reliable action. You should never put any *critical* code in `onunload` as that is never guranteed to execute.

Comment: the "return message to display" doesn't work for me, I always get the "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave " message, not matter what. 
Is this possible to change this message?

Comment: yeap, it's a browser thing. It works in IE9 and Chrome but FF always uses the built in message. Thanks Mrchief

Comment: That's an intentional feature in FF, designed to prevent malware sites from over-riding the normal message with something that might confuse users and having them click the wrong button to trap them on the site

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to try to add some other things like form. But something simple is:

EDIT: Fixed HTML;

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript">
function mymessage()
{
alert("This message was triggered from the onunload event");
}
</script>
</head>

<body onbeforeunload="mymessage()">

<p>close this window and watch the warning box come up!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers have said, you can use a handler for `beforeunload`. To do this, you can use an eventListener:

```
addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
  // Do things before the page is closed.
  event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

`event.preventDefault()` displays a message asking the user to confirm that they want to leave. You can also do something else like autosave without displaying a confirmation message.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event), returning a string or setting `event.returnValue` to activate the confirmation message is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i use on my website

```
`
    /** Show Loader before unloading the document */
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', async function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        start_loader()
    
    })
`
```